# Calculating cell width in UICollectionView inside ContainerView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView and I have implemented the delegate to calculate the width of my cells for 0 spacing between cells.

It works great on its own, but when I have it inside a container view less than the size of the device, iOS incorrectly works out the spacing between the cells adding a horizontal space I don't want.

I have verified the width I am using to calculate the cell size is correct, so I'm not sure what is causing the problem.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let widthPerItem = view.frame.width / itemsPerRow

    return CGSize(width: widthPerItem, height: 60)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was actually related to my uicollectionviewcontroller not correctly sizing to it's parent container view.  Changing to a uiviewcontroller with an embedded uicollectionview plus constraints fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating your cell size based upon the size of the `view`.  Since the `collectionView` doesn't take up the full width of the screen, you are getting the incorrect value.  Instead, you should base your calculation on the width of the `collectionView` itself.

Use the `bounds` of the `collectionView` instead of the `frame` of the `view`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
  let widthPerItem = collectionView.bounds.width / itemsPerRow

  return CGSize(width: widthPerItem, height: 60)
}
```

Comment: thanks, it didnt really correct the problem, but it has lead me in the right direction.  the collectionview width is actually the same as the device width, which is not what i want, so that means my collectionview is too big and not being constrained to my containerview, ill take another look at my constraints and report back :)

Comment: In either case, you should always calculate your cell width based upon the collectionView's width.